# What is the Warning ID of the "No XML encryptor configured." warning

Tags: c#, logging, .net-6.0, suppress-warnings

I am trying to suppress the warning:
`No XML encryptor configured. Key {xxx} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.` and am having the hardest time finding the warning ID for it.

The warning is generated by this code:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/ed303a13b4202b782b8b8638a4fc56187afa8cf0/src/aspnetcore/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/LoggingExtensions.cs#L142

However, `35` is **not** the warning ID, or more precisely, adding `<NoWarn>35</NoWarn>` to the `csproj` didn't prevent it from showing up in the log.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is asking about a runtime warning but treating it as a compile-time warning.

Answer (score 0):

Voting to close my question as this is a runtime warning which can not be suppressed in the same way a compile-time warning can be.